Why does this happen when the parent of ProviderManager is not specified in spring?
I have a question while using Spring Security.
Currently, the security config is configured as follows.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
    private val userDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService,
    private val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder,
    private val jwtAuthenticationFilter: JwtAuthenticationFilter,
)  {

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.httpBasic { it.disable() }
            .sessionManagement{ it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
            .formLogin{it.disable()}
            .csrf{it.disable()}
            .headers{
                it.frameOptions{ rs ->
                    rs.sameOrigin()
                }
            }
            .authorizeHttpRequests{
                it.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/*").permitAll()
                it.requestMatchers("/api/v1/report/**").authenticated()
            }
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)

        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(http: HttpSecurity): AuthenticationManager {
        val authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder::class.java)
        authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build()
    }
}

The problem is that the parent of ProviderManager exists, so when checking the user, if the ID exists but the password is incorrect, the password is checked twice.
public class ProviderManager implements AuthenticationManager, MessageSourceAware, InitializingBean { 
...
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException { 
        ...
        if (result == null && this.parent != null) {
            try {
                parentResult = this.parent.authenticate(authentication);
                result = parentResult;
            } catch (ProviderNotFoundException var12) {
            } catch (AuthenticationException var13) {
                parentException = var13;
                lastException = var13;
            }
        }

Why does this happen? Because of this, the user table is being queried twice, and the count of the number of login attempts is increasing twice. What should I do to fix this?
2024-09-13T14:32:41.200+09:00 DEBUG 19568 --- [TESTREPORT] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/v1/auth/login
2024-09-13T14:32:41.200+09:00 DEBUG 19568 --- [TESTREPORT] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-09-13T14:32:41.201+09:00 DEBUG 19568 --- [TESTREPORT] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /api/v1/auth/login
start login
Hibernate: select u1_0.user_key,u1_0.auth_level,u1_0.id,u1_0.failed_attempts,u1_0.last_modify_time,u1_0.pwd,u1_0.state from user u1_0 where u1_0.id=? and u1_0.state<>?
Hibernate: select r1_0.user_key,r1_0.client_code,r1_0.cont_code from user_role r1_0 where r1_0.user_key=?
2024-09-13T14:32:41.631+09:00 DEBUG 19568 --- [TESTREPORT] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
Hibernate: select u1_0.user_key,u1_0.auth_level,u1_0.id,u1_0.failed_attempts,u1_0.last_modify_time,u1_0.pwd,u1_0.state from user u1_0 where u1_0.id=? and u1_0.state<>?
2024-09-13T14:32:41.828+09:00 DEBUG 19568 --- [TESTREPORT] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value

